# How should I install jpeg62 for Synfig Studio?

Tags: 12.04, software-center, dependencies

I would like to install [Synfig Studio](http://www.synfig.org/) 0.63 on a computer without an Internet connection.

At installation, it says to install the "JPEG62" dependency. I have downloaded this but the Software Centre is not enabling the install button. How should I install this dependency?

Comment: What exactly did you download to install jpeg62? Please edit your question to specify the URL where you downloaded it from.

Comment: I have downloaded synfig studio 0.63 from official. Then it has given me a error for libjpeg62 , i have downloaded it from ubuntu.com only but when going to install using software centre ... it is not allowing to install (even not enabling the install button in Software centre).

Comment: Are you manually downloading the libjpeg62 package and then trying to open it with the Software Centre? If so, try opening the Software Centre directly, enter `libjpeg62` in the search box, select the package when it appears below, and the Install button should appear to the right.

Comment: I don't have internet connection available at the specific computer, SO Yes I have manually download and Install libjpeg62 file. Can I find the same from any other Synfig-Running linux computer ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

To install `libjpeg62` whilst offline, you'll need to download the .deb files for all its dependencies (see [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libjpeg62)) that you don't already have installed as well as the package itself. You would also need all the sub-dependencies, so doing this by hand can quickly become tedious. If you go down that route, once you've downloaded all the .deb files and copied them onto your unconnected computer, install them by running the following in a terminal:

```
dpkg --install <filename1> <filename2> <etc...>
```

If you have no way of getting this computer connected to the Internet, though, you might want to look at the answers to this question if you are going to need to install anything else in future: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)